# How to add delay inside async forEach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, async-await, settimeout

I have a trading script that gets values from "coin" object, which is filled by an API call, then iterates inside `async forEach` loop, then sends trade orders to the server.

The server requires at least 100 ms between each request. I used `setTimeout` with promise, but I can see results coming to console all at once so server bans after a while.

How should I design delaying?
`js`

```
Object.keys(coin).forEach(async function(key) {
 const coinz = coin[key];
  let line1 = sellcoinCalc("sell", coinz.usdPair, coinz.usdOrder)
  let line2 = buycoinCalc("buy", coinz.usdtPair, line1)          
  let result = line2-line1
 if (result > 0){
  console.log(result)
  }
 if (result >= profit){
      await sellcoinTrade("sell", coinz.usdPair, coinz.usdOrder)
      await buycoinTrade("buy", coinz.usdtPair, line1)            
  }
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: You can use a setTimeout function

Comment: Another solution would be using streams like in rxjs library.

Comment: i need a solution within asynchronous functions

Comment: In order for this to work the `forEach` callback would have to be `await`ed by the inner workings of forEach.  Pretty sure that's not the case.  You will have to add the wait part some other way.

Answer (score 4):

Use `for` loop instead of `forEach` and wrap the whole stuff into an async function:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const tradeFn = async () => {
  try {
    for (let i in coin) {
      await sleep(200);
      const coinz = coin[i];
      await sellcoinTrade(coinz /* etc */);
      // etc
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // handle rejections
  }
}
```

Comment: Do i have to use for loop ? , forEach method is simpler for complex coin object

Comment: Yes, but do not work asynchronously for some reason. This basic `for` loop or the `for (let i in coin)` solution will work.

Comment: Alternatively you can use for...await loop but it requires custom iterator function.